# ¿Como mostrar una lista / array PHP en una alerta javascript (AlertifyJS)?

Tags: php, javascript

Esta es mi duda, porque en este ejemplo estoy haciendo un array con javacript, donde realmente ese array lo hago en una consulta sql(PDO) y lo envío en un `onclick='verProveedores(<?php echo json_encode($datos);?>)';`
Hasta ahí no hay problema porque lo envía correctamente, la cuestión es que no sé como mostrar varios valores de ese array en un alert, solo he podido imprimir solo valores independientes, en este caso en un `Alertify.alert();`
Por eso el propósito de este post, agradezco sus ayudas.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/alertify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/themes/default.min.css" />
<html>
  <head>
    <tittle>Mostrar lista en js</tittle>
  </head>

  <body><h2>
    <div id="labelalmacen" onclick='verProveedores();'> Haga Click para mostrar lista.
    </div></h2>
    <script>
   var proveedores=[{"nombre_proveedor":"PROVEEDOR1","0":"PROVEEDOR1"},{"nombre_proveedor":"PROVEEDOR2","0":"PROVEEDOR2"},{"nombre_proveedor":"PROVEEDOR3","0":"PROVEEDOR3"},{"nombre_proveedor":"PROVEEDOR4","0":"PROVEEDOR4"}];
      function verProveedores() {
        alertify.alert("Lista Proveedores:", proveedores[1].nombre_proveedor);
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESUELTO]
Seguí investigando hasta que dí como hacer para imprimir varios valores del mismo campo en un alert usando Alertifyjs, todo estaba en la variable `data='';`
quien es y se usará como contador para que muestre varias veces el mensaje y lo apile como array al usarse el mismo en el ciclo `for(){}` justamente dentro del ciclo se usa ella misma al final `data=('mensaje'+ array)+data;`<---aquí el truco, sumarlo a ella misma y luego colocarlo en un alert.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/alertify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/alertify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.11.0/build/css/themes/default.min.css" />
<html>

<head>
  <tittle>Mostrar lista en AlertifyJS</tittle>
</head>
<style>
  #labelalmacen:hover {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <h2>
    <div id="labelalmacen" onclick='verProveedoresAlertifyJS("arrayconvalores");'> Haga click aquí para mostrar lista Almacen con proveedores (AlertifyJS).
    </div><br>
    <div id="labelalmacen" onclick='verProveedoresAlertifyJS("arraysinvalores");'> Haga click aquí para mostrar lista Almacen sin proveedores (AlertifyJS).
    </div>
<br>
    <div id="labelalmacen" onclick='verProveedoresAlertpordefecto("arrayconvalores");'> Haga click aquí para mostrar lista Almacen con proveedores (Alert por defecto).
    </div><br>
    <div id="labelalmacen" onclick='verProveedoresAlertpordefecto("arraysinvalores");'> Haga click aquí para mostrar lista Almacen sin proveedores (Alert por defecto).
    </div>
  </h2>
  <script>
    function verProveedoresAlertifyJS(valor) {
      if (valor == 'arrayconvalores') {
        var proveedores = [{
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR1",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR1"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR2",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR2"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR3",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR3"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR4",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR4"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR5",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR5"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR6",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR6"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR7",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR7"
        }];
      } else if (valor == 'arraysinvalores') {
        var proveedores = '';
      }

      data = '';

      for (i = 0; i < proveedores.length; i++) {

        data = ('(' + i + ') Proveedor: ' + proveedores[i].nombre_proveedor + '<br><br>') + data;
      }
      if (proveedores.length == 0) {
        alertify.warning("Este almacen no tiene proveedores.");
      } else {
        alertify.alert('Lista de Proveedores.', data).set({ closableByDimmer:false});
      }
    }
    // ALERTA POR DEFECTO
    function verProveedoresAlertpordefecto(valor) {
      if (valor == 'arrayconvalores') {
        var proveedores = [{
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR1",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR1"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR2",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR2"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR3",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR3"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR4",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR4"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR5",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR5"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR6",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR6"
        }, {
          "nombre_proveedor": "PROVEEDOR7",
          "0": "PROVEEDOR7"
        }];
      } else if (valor == 'arraysinvalores') {
        var proveedores = '';
      }

      data = '';

      for (i = 0; i < proveedores.length; i++) {

        data = ('(' + i + ') Proveedor: ' + proveedores[i].nombre_proveedor + '\n\n') + data;
      }
      if (proveedores.length == 0) {
        alert("Este almacen no tiene proveedores.");
      } else {
        alert('Lista de Proveedores.\n' + data);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [ACTUALIZACION]
Para que no se vea recorrido desde el ultimo hasta el primer valor, solamente tienen que cambiar la posición de la variable `data` dentro del ciclo `for` así:
ANTES-> `data = ('(' + i + ') Proveedor: ' + proveedores[i].nombre_proveedor + '<br><br>') + data;` <--ponerlo en el principio.
ASÍ-> `data = data+('(' + i + ') Proveedor: ' + proveedores[i].nombre_proveedor + '<br><br>');`